# Как определить угол наклона головы и наличие лишних предметов в кадре с помощью OpenCV c++

Tags: c++, opencv

Делаю программу для анализа фото требованиям паспорта, и хотелось узнать как проверить наклон головы, смотрит ли человек в камеру, и плюсом как можно определить есть ли лишние предметы в кадре.

Comment: В OpenCV есть детектор глаз - можно найти глаза и задать интервал наклона линии, проходящих через центры обнаруженных областей.  С лишними предметами задача творческая - можно, например, анализировать градиент и выделять области с большим перепадом яркости по градиенту. Предварительно можно поискать корпус человека или задать область, в которой не нужно искать посторонние объекты.

Comment: Я придумал как проверять на наклон, так как у меня изображение ограничено по размеру, я нахожу точки лица, и проверяю точки носа в определенном диапазоне. @EugenyShtanov

Comment: @EugenyShtanov, я тоже думал об этом, что можно задать область где не надо искать, но вот как задать  эту область?

Comment: В этом и заключается творческая часть задания. Можно маску накладывать, можно корпус искать, можно градиент анализировать. Я надеюсь, Вы на белом фоне собираетесь фотографировать? В инете есть программы, которые справляются с этим и при произвольном фоне.

Comment: @EugenyShtanov я выделил область и закрасил его цветом фона, и ищу контуры на фото, и потом с помощью поиска объектов нахожу эти контуры. Так я решил эту проблему